# small y greek symbol in overleaf

Tags: latex, symbols, overleaf

How could I use a small 'y' symbol like greek in overleaf (latex)?

[image]

X seems like chi, however, I couldn't find greek 'y'.

The symbols are written in the page 40 of a book 2nd ed. 'The Elements of Statistical Learning -Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction'.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/List_of_Greek_letters_and_math_symbols

Comment: I wonder whether the symbol is not available...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in the other answer, the small greek gamma comes very close...
On second thought it looks like the "classic" *x* and *y* in somekind of math font, due to the italic like representation. The following should do the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eucal}

\begin{document}
  \[\CMcal{X,Y}\]
\end{document}
```

With the result:

[image]
In case you are looking for a mathematical symbol or any symbol in latex, have a look at [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).
This tool comes in very handy, if you have to classify a symbol;-)

Answer (score -2):

It's \gamma. That should work!

Answer (score -2):

You may try to use math font packages.

[image]

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, eucal, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{xparse}

$\mathcal{X, Y}$
$\mathbf{X, Y}$
$\mathrm{X, Y}$
$\mathds{X, Y}$
$\mathfrak{X, Y}$
$\mathbb{X, Y}$
$\mathbf{X, Y}$
$\mathit{X, Y}$
$\mathrm{X, Y}$
$\mathscr{X, Y}$
$\mathsf{X, Y}$
```